# Problems with reading values as formula instead of data

Tags: python, numpy, python-3.6, openpyxl

When I want to read my Excel:

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook
import numpy as np

"read Excel"
wb = load_workbook('Libro1.xlsx')
hoja_1 = wb.get_sheet_by_name('1')

x = np.zeros(hoja_1.max_row)
y = np.zeros(hoja_1.max_row)

for i in range(0, hoja_1.max_row):
    x[i] = hoja_1.cell(row = i + 1, column = 1).value
    y[i] = hoja_1.cell(row = i + 1, column = 2).value

print(x)
print(y)
```

> I get an error in:
>
> ```
> x[i] = hoja_1.cell(row = i + 1, column = 1).value
> ```
>
> **ValueError**: could not convert string to float: **'=A1+1'**

Comment: You probably want to use `data_only=True` when opening the workbook. Also, just use `ws.iter_rows()` and not a range object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

x and y are  object. Convert that into list before assigning values.

Try this:

x = list(np.zeros(hoja_1.max_row))
y = list(np.zeros(hoja_1.max_row))

Answer (score 0):

One but rather rare possibility is that a cell in 'Libro1.xlsx' marked as text format, which prevents it from recalulating.

When you open an Excel file, do you see the value of `=A1+1` recalculated, or as text?
In any case, apply the simplest numeric formatting to all cells in Excel file (select cells and choose format), also eliminate any conditional formatting.

Similar problem described here: https://bitbucket.org/openpyxl/openpyxl/issues/699/valueerror-could-not-convert-string-to. Make sure your `openpyxl` version is up to date.